# If volume of cone is halved, how will it affect height and radius

Tags: geometry

A cone glass with radius 8 cm and height 9 cm is filled to its brim. Half the liquid is thrown out. what is the height and radius of the new cone formed by the liquid?

Comment: Volume is "distance cubed", so a smart guess would be that the new radius and height are the original ones divides by $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For similar 3D shapes, if $L$ is some linear measure of the shape (e.g. radius, height, circumference, diagonal length, etc...) then the volume is proportional to $L^3$.

If $V_f$ is your final volume and $V_0$ is your initial volume, the problem tells you that $V_f=\frac{1}{2}V_0$. Thus, considering the radii you will have $r_f^3=\frac{1}{2}r_0^3$, hence $r_f=r_0\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}=8\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}$, and similarly the new height is $9\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}$.